# Backup SSRS Encryption Keys Using Powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0, ssrs-2008-r2

I have made the following script from google for backing up the SSRS Encryption keys:

```
cls
$pwd = "sa@123@123"
$SSRSClass = Get-Wmiobject -namespace "root\microsoft\sqlserver\reportserver\rs_BPSSRS\v10\admin" -class "MSReportServer_ConfigurationSetting"

$key = $SSRSClass.BackupEncryptionKey($pwd)
$stream = [System.IO.File]::Create("c:\\SSRS.snk", $key.KeyFile.Length)
$stream.Write($key.KeyFile, 0, $key.KeyFile.Length)
$stream.Close()
```

But I'm getting the following errors:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'BackupEn
cryptionKey'.
At line:5 char:38
+ $key = $SSRSClass.BackupEncryptionKey <<<< ($results)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (BackupEncryptionKey:String) [], RuntimeEx 
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Exception calling "Create" with "2" argument(s): "Positive number required.
Parameter name: bufferSize"
At line:6 char:35
+ $stream = [System.IO.File]::Create <<<< ("c:\\SSRS.snk", $key.KeyFile.Length)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:7 char:14
+ $stream.Write <<<< ($key.KeyFile, 0, $key.KeyFile.Length)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Write:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:8 char:14
+ $stream.Close <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Close:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I'm using powershell v2. I tried finding about this but no luck. There are around 50+ SSRS servers in our environment and doing backup manually is tiresome. Hence, we came up with this automation. Kindly provide your comments.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code should do the trick:

```
$ComputerName = "."
$KeyFolder = "C:\Temp"
$KeyPassword = "sa@123@123"
$TimeStamp = Get-Date -Format "-yyyyMMdd-HHmmss"

Get-WmiObject -Namespace "Root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer" -Class "__Namespace" -ComputerName $ComputerName |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name |
    % {
        $NameSpaceRS = $_
        $InstanceName = $NameSpaceRS.SubString(3)
        $KeyFileName = Join-Path -Path $KeyFolder -ChildPath ($InstanceName + $Timestamp + ".snk")
        "Found Reporting Services in instance '$($InstanceName)' on $($ComputerName); will save key to '$($KeyFileName)' ..."
        $SQLVersion = (Get-WmiObject -Namespace "Root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\$($NameSpaceRS)" -Class "__Namespace" -ComputerName $ComputerName).Name
        $SSRSClass = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "Root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\$($NameSpaceRS)\$($SQLVersion)\Admin" -Query "SELECT * FROM MSReportServer_ConfigurationSetting WHERE InstanceName='$($InstanceName)'" -ComputerName $ComputerName
        $Key = $SSRSClass.BackupEncryptionKey($KeyPassword)
        If ($Key.HRESULT -ne 0) {
            $Key.ExtendedErrors -join "`r`n" | Write-Error
        } Else {
            $Stream = [System.IO.File]::Create($KeyFileName, $Key.KeyFile.Length)
            $Stream.Write($Key.KeyFile, 0, $Key.KeyFile.Length)
            $Stream.Close()
        }
    }
```

The errors that you have mentioned are because your code is trying to fetch information from duplicate entries. Meaning, if you try the above code on the server where only one named instance of SSRS is running, then I suppose it will succeed. Just try this piece and give your comments.
CHEERS.

Comment: Hi, how can i backup encryption key from one server and restore that key to another server? I want to put ReportServer in sync on my server1 and serve2